# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 (cannot refer to member function)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, class, g++

I got compile error as following while compiling a C++ program on Mac 10.11.4 using g++ command `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o test`.

But the Xcode can successfully build and run. I couldn't find out the error and I don't know whether the Xcode built it correctly. Could somebody help me out?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "KM::execute_bfs()", referenced from:
      _main in main-34d254.o
  "KM::init(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > > >*, long)", referenced from:
      _main in main-34d254.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

There are at all three files. "main.cpp", "km.cpp" and "km.h".
I put the class function in "km.cpp" and the definition of class in "km.h".

In "main.cpp", code is like:

```
long nv;
vector<vector<float>> weight;
int readin() {
    ...
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        vector<float> tp;
        tp.resize(nv, 0.0);
        weight.push_back(tp);
    }
}
int main() {
    KM km;
    km.init(&weight, nv);
    km.execute_bfs();
}
```

In "km.cpp", I define all the member functions as:

```
long KM::init(vector< vector<float> > *input_weight, long input_max_v_num) { ... }
bool KM::bfs(long x) {...}
long KM::execute_bfs() {
    ...
    bfs(x);
    ...
}
```

And in "km.h", my code is like:

```
class KM {
public:
    vector< vector<float> > *weight;

    long max_v_num;
    float lx[MAX_NUM], ly[MAX_NUM];

    long init(vector< vector<float> > *input_weight, long input_max_v_num);
    bool bfs(long x);
    long execute_bfs();
};
```

I ignore some details and display what I think may matter in the previous codes.

The error happens while compiling main.cpp on Mac 10.11.4 using g++ command `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o test` but works well using Xcode.

The error shows that I haven't defined the KM::execute_bfs() and KM::init(), but I have actually done this, as the previous code shows. Is there anybody who could help?

Comment: Where on the command line did you specify to compile `km.cpp`?

Comment: Oh, I see... Thanks a lot. And sorry for the silly question. Questions with similar titles are too much to find what I want, thank you and Bo Persson.